# Publishing in multi-project solution fails with only one project can be specified

Tags: .net-core, csproj, sln-file

Hello i am trying to run `dotnet -c Release [sourcepath] --output [destination]` a project in a `.sln` that has multiple projects.
The file-structure of the solution is like this:

```
 RootFolder
     -.sln
      Folder1
         - Csproj1
      Folder2
         - Csproj2   //i want to publish this one (lets say ipotetically)
```

When i am running `dotnet publish -c Release [path]/RootFolder/folder1 --output [destination]` i keep getting the error:

**Error**:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: Release

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

Comment: For me it does not happen. Maybe you will show us the csproj files.

Comment: did you ever solve this i have the same issue

Comment: Yes i solved it using this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProject)